# I'm trying to create a sorting algorithm to find all combinations that would yield a certain result, but keep getting an error about the index

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

the data is a numpy array (784,)

here is the sorting function:

```
while flips < max_flip:
    flipped_accuracy = 0
    combination = []
    while flipped_accuracy <= original_accuracy:

        i_vals = []
        for i in range(flips):
            i_vals.append(i)

        index = 1
        last_added = 0
        while flips - index > 0:
            for i in i_vals:
                ind = indexes[i]
                combination.append(index_accuracies[ind])
            if np.mean(combination) > original_accuracy:
                flip_combinations.append(combination)
                last_added = 0
            else:
                last_added += 1

            if i_vals[-index] < 784:
                if last_added > 10 or (i_vals[0] == 783 and i_vals[-1] == 783):
                    flips += 1
                    break
                i_vals[-index] += 1


                if index > 1:
                    index -= 1
            else:
                index += 1

augemented_images = []
for c in flip_combinations:
    z = pixel_flipper(x0_test, c)
    augemented_images.append(z)`
```

and the error I keep getting is

> ```
> ind = indexes[i]
> ```
>
> IndexError: index 784 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 784

Comment: what do you think that error message means?

Comment: I've been playing around with this for hours and am lost. max_flips is 784/2, so I'm not sure how it would go to index 784

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code seems to be the likely culprit:

```
if i_vals[-index] < 784:
    # ...
    i_vals[-index] += 1
```

If `i_vals[-index]` is `783` it will be increased to `784`, so the next time that value is used as the index it will cause the error.